# How do you create a menuItem alternate in orchard for different Zones

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I created an alternate for the main menu called `MenuItemLink-main-menu-MainNavigation-MenuItem.cshtml` because I want to render the menu differently in a Zone called main navigation. vs other places I am using the same menu on the page like the footer. I copied the `MenuItem` shape and renamed it (`MenuItemLink-main-menu-MainNavigation-MenuItem.cshtml`) everytime I run it I get an overflow because of the following line.

```
var renderedMenuItemLink = Display(Model);
```

can someone please explain to me why this is happening and the best way to create a zone based shapes for the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied markup from one shape (MenuItem) and paste it to another shape (MenuItemLink).

1. MenuItem calls Display for MenuItemLink
2. Then you calls Display for MenuItemLink inside MenuItemLink - this is an infinite loop.

**For add alternate inside theme for MenuItemLink:**

First. Create alternate for menu widget (Parts.MenuWidget.cshtml)

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Widgets.Models;
@{
    var widgetPart = ((IContent)Model.ContentItem).As<WidgetPart>();
    Model.Menu.Zone = widgetPart.Zone;
}
```

Second. Create alternate for menu item (MenuItem.cshtml) and add one line (after line Model.Metadata.Type = "MenuItemLink";)

```
Model.Metadata.Type = "MenuItemLink";
(Model as Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes.Shape).Metadata.OnDisplaying(action => 
    action.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add("MenuItemLink__Zone__" + (string)Model.Menu.Zone)
);
```

**For add alternate inside theme for MenuItem:**

First. Create alternate for menu widget (Parts.MenuWidget.cshtml)

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Widgets.Models;
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;
@{
    var widgetPart = ((IContent)Model.ContentItem).As<WidgetPart>();
    var items = Model.Menu.Items as List<dynamic>;
    AddMenuItemAlternate(items, widgetPart.Zone);
}
@functions{
    public void AddMenuItemAlternate(List<dynamic> items, string zoneName)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.Metadata.Alternates.Add("MenuItem__Zone__" + zoneName);
            var subitems = (List<dynamic>)Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(item.Items);
            AddMenuItemAlternate(subitems, zoneName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2015.08:**

I create module that adds widget name and zone name alternates for menu, menuItem and menu item link shapes. You can download one from orchard gallery https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.MainBit.Navigation

Comment: Is this the only way to have alternates based on the zone they are in? I am currently trying to display a Summary display in Content with a different alternate to the AsideSecond Summary.

Comment: No. Better way is implementing IShapeTableProvider. For your purpose, Look at Orchard.Core.Contents.Shapes and Orchard.Widgets.Shapes classes.